# Canvas saving and restoring

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that i need to change the height for after every bit of content is added - the only way for me to get a dynamic canvas height. I'm trying to use `save` and `restore` so i don't lose all the styles, settings etc.

I can't get `save` and `restore` to work. I must be doing something wrong or is this the wrong approach?

```
function DrawLeftText(text) {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPaper');

 if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.textAlign = 'left';
    context.font = 'normal 20px Monkton';
    context.fillText(text, leftPosition, cursor);
    context.textAlign = 'start';

    context.save();


 }
}

function restoreSettings(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPaper');
   if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     context.restore();
  }  
}


function onDrawReceipt() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPaper');

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.textBaseline = 'top';

        lineSpace      =  20;
        leftPosition   =  0;
    // centerPosition =  canvas.width       / 2;
        centerPosition = (canvas.width + 26) / 2;
     // rightPosition  =  canvas.width;
        rightPosition  = (canvas.width - 0);

//      cursor = 0;
        cursor = 80;

    context.fillRect(25, cursor - 2, 526, 2); cursor += lineSpace;
    context.fillRect(25, cursor - 2, 526, 2); cursor += lineSpace;
    DrawCenterText(company['name']); cursor += lineSpace;
    DrawCenterText(company['address']['address_line_1']); cursor += lineSpace;
    DrawCenterText(company['address']['city'].toUpperCase()); cursor += lineSpace;
    DrawCenterText(company['address']['postcode']); cursor += lineSpace;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height += 20);

    **//increasing the height and then trying to restore**

    restoreSettings();

  }
}
```

////// Additional attempt. I've tried the following too without luck.
////// None of the content appears despite setting the height before adding the content??

```
var header = function headerSection(){

      var height = cursor;
      canvas.height += height;

      context.textBaseline = 'top';
      lineSpace      =  20;
      leftPosition   =  0;
      centerPosition = (canvas.width + 26) / 2;
      rightPosition  = (canvas.width - 0);

      console.log(height);
      console.log(context);

      context.fillRect(25, cursor - 2, 526, 2); cursor += lineSpace;
      context.fillRect(25, cursor - 2, 526, 2); cursor += lineSpace;
      DrawCenterText(company['name']); cursor += lineSpace;
      DrawCenterText(company['address']['address_line_1']); cursor += lineSpace;
      DrawCenterText(company['address']['city'].toUpperCase()); cursor += lineSpace;
      DrawCenterText(company['address']['postcode']); cursor += lineSpace;


      console.log(canvas.height);

      return;

    }

    header()
```

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the canvas element will always reset its context to the default style states. (`.save & .restore` will not let the context styles survive a resizing)

The common canvas pattern to deal with changes to canvas content is:

- Save data (eg your `company`)
- Either save context styles as javascript variables or embed the style changes in functions (eg a specialized function to set appropriate styles and redraw the company heading).
- Resize (or clear) the canvas
- Redraw all the content using the saved data and saved styles/functions.

**Example code:**

*Click "Full page" to see full receipt*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var lineSpace=20;
var leftOfForm=25;
var topOfForm=80;
var testingItems=110;

var company={
  name:'MyCompany, Inc',
  address:{
    address_line_1: '123 Main Street',
    city:'Anytown, Anywhere',
    postcode:'12345'
  }
}

var lineItems=[];
addLineItem(testingItems,'Description of sku#'+testingItems,testingItems);

$('#test').click(function(){
  testingItems++;
  addLineItem(testingItems,'Description of sku#'+testingItems,testingItems);
  draw();
});

draw();

function addLineItem(sku,description,price){
  lineItems.push({
    sku:sku,
    description:description,
    price:price
  });
}

function draw(){
  // note: changing canvas.height auto-erases the content also
  canvas.height=topOfForm+(6+2+lineItems.length)*lineSpace;
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawHeader(leftOfForm,topOfForm);
  for(var i=0;i<lineItems.length;i++){
    drawLineItem(lineItems[i],leftOfForm,topOfForm+(6+2+i)*lineSpace);
  }
}

function drawHeader(left,cursor){
  var cx=canvas.width/2;
  var line=function(linecount){ return(cursor+lineSpace*linecount); }

  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(left,line(0)-2);
  ctx.lineTo(526,line(0)-2);
  ctx.moveTo(left,line(1)-2);
  ctx.lineTo(526,line(1)-2);
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.font='18px verdana';
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='top';
  ctx.fillText(company.name,cx,line(2));
  ctx.fillText(company.address.address_line_1,cx,line(3));
  ctx.fillText(company.address.city,cx,line(4));
  ctx.fillText(company.address.postcode,cx,line(5));

  ctx.restore();
}

function drawLineItem(item,left,cursor){

  ctx.save();

  ctx.font='14px verdana';
  ctx.textAlign='left';
  ctx.textBaseline='top';
  ctx.fillText(item.sku,left,cursor);
  ctx.fillText(item.description,left+40,cursor);
  ctx.textAlign='right';
  ctx.fillText(item.price,left+450,cursor);

  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=test>Add another line</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=550 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: could you provide a quick example please?

Comment: I've added a quick example which encapsulates drawing the header in one function and the line-items in another function.  The styling required to draw the header is inside the header function--same for the line-items function. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach at the cost of a little more memory (if you're dealing with very large canvases you will of course have to weight in memory concern) -

- Use an internal larger canvas representing a max size (or block size<sup>1</sup>)
- Keep a value representing the current height (not actual)
- Create a visual canvas in the document at the height stored in the value
- For every draw operation, draw to the internal canvas
- When done, set the visual canvas height using the current height value, draw internal canvas to visual one

## Example 1

This example uses this technique to draw text at random color. As you can see we do not need to redraw the text when we change the visual canvas' size, we just copy everything from the internal canvas which also contains the current styles (font, font size, fill style).

```js
var vcanvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    vctx = vcanvas.getContext("2d"),
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    line = 25,
    maxHeight = 7 * line,
    currentHeight = line,
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnowxyzABCD#/&%/(#)=!LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split(""),
    x = 0, y = 0, ch;

vcanvas.height = currentHeight;

// internal canvas setup
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";

// draw someting to internal canvas:
(function loop() {
  ch = chars[(Math.random() * chars.length)|0];
  ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (360*Math.random()) + ",75%,50%)";
  ctx.fillText(ch, x, y);
  x += ctx.measureText(ch).width;
  if (x > canvas.width) { 
    x = 0; y += line; currentHeight += line;
  }
  
  // copy to visual canvas:
  if (currentHeight < maxHeight) vcanvas.height = currentHeight;
  vctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, currentHeight, 
                         0, 0, canvas.width, currentHeight);
  
  
  if (currentHeight < maxHeight) setTimeout(loop, 50);
})();
```

```css
body{background:#eee} canvas{background:#fff}
canvas{border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

<sup>1)</sup> If you are dealing with "infinite" height you want to split the process into blocks. Set internal canvas to block size, when exceeded enlarge internal canvas with new block size - but here you will have to do full redraw and setup again.

And this leads to option 2: The latter technique can be used directly with the visual canvas as well, and you can use CSS to clip it putting it inside a div element which you style with height and overflow:hidden.

## Example 2

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    div = document.querySelector("div"),
    line = 25,
    maxHeight = 7 * line,
    currentHeight = line,
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnowxyzABCD#/&%/(#)=!LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split(""),
    x = 0, y = 0, ch;

// set canvas to max height, div to clip height
canvas.height = maxHeight;
div.style.height = currentHeight + "px";

// canvas setup
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";

// draw someting to the canvas:
(function loop() {
  ch = chars[(Math.random() * chars.length)|0];
  ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (360*Math.random()) + ",75%,50%)";
  ctx.fillText(ch, x, y);
  x += ctx.measureText(ch).width;
  if (x > canvas.width) { 
    x = 0; y += line; currentHeight += line;
  }
  
  // copy to visual canvas:
  if (currentHeight < maxHeight) {
    div.style.height = currentHeight + "px";  // increase clipping height
    setTimeout(loop, 50)
  }
})();
```

```css
body{background:#eee} canvas{background:#fff}
div{border:1px solid #000; overflow:hidden; width:302px}
```

```html
<div><canvas></canvas></div>
```